# Does Android restart bound service in separate process automatically after it is crashed?

Tags: android, service

I have a bound service in separate process. It crashes occasionally due to the oem native libs on certain phones. I am trying to make the app recover from it.

It seems if I kill the service process from adb, the service is always restarted by itself, and onServiceConnected is always called. But if I throw an exception for testing, for the second time the service is not restarted.

How would I get a consistent behavior? I can rebind in onServiceDisconnected, but for the case the service is restarted by itself, I would get two connections.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. The key is to rebind with the same connection. It is noop if the service has been bound with the same connection.